# Let $F(r)=\sum_{k=1}^m{|P(rz_k)|^2}$ for $r>0$. Prove that the function $F(r)$ is increasing if $m>n>0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contest-math

Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with complex coefficients. Further, let $$z_k=e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{m}}$$ for some $m$ and $k=1,2,...,m$. In other words, $z_1,\cdots z_m$ are the $m$th roots of unity. Let $$F(r)=\sum_{k=1}^m{|P(rz_k)|^2}$$ for $r>0$. Prove that the function $F(r)$ is increasing if $m>n>0$.

My attempt: Denote $P(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n{a_kz^k}$. Note that $$|P(rz_k)|^2=P(rz_k)\overline{P(rz_k)}=\left( \sum_{k=1}^n{a_k \left(rz^k \right)} \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^n{\overline{a_k} r^k \overline{z}^k } \right)$$

Then I don't know how to proceed from here. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: Found a solution. I'm questionning if a proof cannot be derived from PARSEVAL equality.

Answer (score 0):

Following as you started and denote $P(z)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j z^j$. You get:

$$\vert P(z) \vert^2=P(z) \bar{P(z)} = \sum_{0 \le j,l \le n} a_j \bar{a_l}z^j \bar{z}^l$$ Replacing $z$ by $r z_k$ and making the sum:

$$F(r) = \sum_{k=1}^m (\sum_{0 \le j,l \le n} a_j r^{j+l}\bar{a_l}z_k^j \bar{z_k}^l) = \sum_{k=1}^m (\sum_{0 \le j,l \le n} a_j \bar{a_l} r^{j+l} z_k^{j-l}) = \sum_{0 \le j,l \le n} a_j \bar{a_l} r^{j+l} (\sum_{k=1}^m z_k^{j-l})$$

As $n < m$ for $j \neq l$ we cannot have $z_1^{j-l} = 1$ as $\vert j-l \vert < m$. Hence for $j \neq l$ $\sum_{k=1}^m z_k^{j-l} = 0$.

Therefore:

$$F(r) = \sum_{j=0}^n \vert a_k \vert^2 r^{2j} $$

which is an increasing function of $r$.